# How to find limit of this sum?

Tags: limits, summation

I'm trying to find limit of this sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+1)\sqrt{i}}$$

I know I can obtain it from WolframAlpha, but I need to learn a generic way to solve these problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that supposed to be $i$ in the summand rather than $n$?

Comment: Yep, sorry, that was a typo)

Comment: So $ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{(i+1)\sqrt{i}}$ then?

Comment: Now its correct)

Comment: Is there any reason to expect a closed form for the value of the sum of this series?

Comment: Is the answer π/2?

Comment: Wolfram says that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+1)\sqrt{i}} = 1.86003$

Comment: But as I said, I need a solution

Comment: The summand can be re-written as $\dfrac{\sqrt{i}}{i}-\dfrac{\sqrt{i}}{i+1}$. Don't know if that's helpful, however. Perhaps you can get a telescoping sum?

Comment: Can we convert this into an integral?

Comment: Ignoring the term $+1$, the sum converges to $\zeta(3/2)$, which has no closed form (AFAIK). This $+1$ term makes things more complicated.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{i}}{i}-\frac{\sqrt{i+1}}{i+1}$ would be nice because it leads to an easy solution. But we only have $\frac{\sqrt{i}}{i}-\frac{\sqrt{i}}{i+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+1)\sqrt{i}}
=\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{3/2}\sqrt{1-\frac1i}}
=\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k-\frac12}k\frac1{i^k}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k-\frac12}k\sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{k+3/2}}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k-\frac12}k\left(\zeta\left(k+\frac32\right)-1\right).$$